# Postgres regex and special characters

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am using posgresql, and I have encountered an issue with regular expressions and special characters.

```
select regexp_replace('asdf|asdf','|','.');
```

This function returns:

```
.asdf|asdf
```

Desired output:

```
asdf.asdf
```

How I can solve it? Please help :)

Comment: What about `replace('asdf|asdf','|','.')` ?

Comment: @pozs: seems way more suited indeed.

Comment: I dont need to replace all the characters at one, thats the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a special character in regex syntax called alternation, it means "or".

Your regex is selecting the empty string at the beginning of your string.

Try escaping it:

```
select regexp_replace('asdf|asdf','\|','.');
```

---

As @pozs underlined, for this particular task it is way more suited to use a simple `replace`:

```
select replace('asdf|asdf','|','.');
```